# Update Action Bar Style Using Theme AppCompat Light

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying following in style file but unable to change font and text position of action bar. I want to do it in my style sheet.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!-- Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar, Theme.Holo.Light -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: What happens when you apply the the current stye. I notice that your background and textcolor both are white?

Comment: Text color white is in-fact color of action bar (which is green). My question is different.. i want to show action bar text in center and text as bold and size as 25sp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried all the research and finally concluded that it is better to create your custom action bar.

Following are the two very easy steps (got from different threads in different shapes, and compiling here). I hope this will be helpful for anyone (you just need to copy and past in your code)

Step-1: create an XML file at (app/res/layout/) name it as custom_action_bar.xml

Step-2: Paste following code in this file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/green">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Step-3: Paste following code in onCreate function of your activity class located at (app/java/your_package_name/your_activity_name)

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should inherit action bar style from Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar and try to override following items

```
<style name="AppActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't work for me :((((